# randomly change numpy array values

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array data.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,0,4,1,1,2,0],
                 [1,0,0,4,0,1,0],
                 [4,0,4,3,2,1,0],
                 [4,0,1,1,2,1,1]])

print(data)
```

If some non_zero elements (1,2,3,4) have more than 5 counts, I want to randomly extract and keep 5 positions and replace all other positions into 0s.

```
uniques, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
for unique, count in zip(uniques, counts):
    print (unique, count)

    if count > 5:       
       
       ids = np.random.choice(range(count), 5, replace=False)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Keep just 5 positions or all positions of unique, non-zero elements when their counts are more than 5?

Comment: its to keep just 5 positions, if their counts are more than 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uniques, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
for unique, count in zip(uniques, counts):
    print (unique, count)
    if unique != 0 and count > 5:
       ids = np.random.choice(count, count-5, replace=False)
       data[tuple(i[ids] for i in np.where(data == unique))] = 0
```

Comment: what would be an alternative to this line, `data[tuple(i[ids] for i in np.where(data == unique))] = 0`?

Comment: I could not understand that line

Comment: maybe this one more easily to understand,
`x,y = np.where(data == unique)`
`for i in ids: data[x[i],y[i]] = 0`